# UWP - Template10 pageheader ellipsis tabstop on version 1.1.12

Tags: c#, uwp, template10, tabstop

On the latest UWP Template10 version 1.1.12, the 3 ellipsis dot on the pageHeader are now tab stop.

[image]

This was definitely not there on the previous version.
How can tab stop be disabled on this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tab stop behavior of the `MoreButton` in `PageHeader` has been changed in commits on Sep 8, 2016. For more info, please see the [history on GitHub](https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/commit/91abfb2193341cdbff3ae7488fdea560e48c0082#diff-4bfdee5373c6736282f711703bceafbf).

So in the previous version, `MoreButton`'s `IsTabStop` property is set to `False` in [`PageHeaderButton` style](https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/blob/1a948f6de9020ae14c5fcd95457a708ccd5eea34/Template10%20(Library)/Themes/PageHeader.xaml#L7-L8) and now in version 1.1.12, it has been [set to `True` explicitly](https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/blob/91abfb2193341cdbff3ae7488fdea560e48c0082/Template10%20(Library)/Themes/PageHeader.xaml#L920). If you want to disable the tab stop, you can modify `PageHeader`'s template and just remove the newly added line: [`IsTabStop="True"`](https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/blob/91abfb2193341cdbff3ae7488fdea560e48c0082/Template10%20(Library)/Themes/PageHeader.xaml#L920) in `MoreButton`. Or you can copy [the previous version of PageHeader.xaml](https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/blob/1a948f6de9020ae14c5fcd95457a708ccd5eea34/Template10%20(Library)/Themes/PageHeader.xaml) and then merge this resource dictionary in ***App.xaml*** like:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles/Custom.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles/PageHeader.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: Thank you Jay, this is perfect. :)

Comment: Please note that IsTabStop=True is VERY valuable to accessibility users. Remove it as you like, but remember that some users navigate with their mouths, not their mice.